# Injected html code using Mustache in chrome extension with onclick return function not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need some help understanding the following issue on my Chrome extension.
In my extension I have two images. Image #0, which is hard coded in the popup.html page while the second image (image#1) is injected using Mustache template from the popup.js file into the popup.html file as image#1. Both images have exactly the same code. I have verified this by looking at the browser page source output.

Whats suppose to happen: on clicking the mouse on each image a function should be called with an alert message.

Whats happening: The hard corded image(image#0) calls the function and display the alert message while the injected code refuse to call the alert function.

I need help understanding this. I am missing something basic. I will be grateful.

Here is the code:

manifest file....

```
{
 "name": "test",
 "description": "..",
 "version": "1",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "icons": { "128": "images/icon_128.png" },
 "permissions": [ "cookies", "tabs", "background", "storage", "http://*/*",     "https://*/*" ],
 "minimum_chrome_version": "25",

 "content_scripts": [{"all_frames": true,
                   "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
                   "js": ["js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"]
                 }],


"browser_action": {"default_icon": "images/icon.png",
               "default_popup": "html/popup.html",
               "default_title": "test"
        }
}
```

popup.html file....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

  <body>


  <div id="image0">    
     <img class="delWebTile" alt="#" src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
  </div>

  <div id="image1">    
  </div>

    <script src="../js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/mustache-chromeapps.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/popup.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

popup.js file....

```
$('.delWebTile').click(function() {

   alert("I am in delete function");
  });

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

 var webTile = {
 };

 var template = '<img class="delWebTile" alt="#" src="http://placehold.it/300x200">';

var html = Mustache.to_html(template, webTile);
$('#image1').html(html);
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is you are adding the click event binding before the  tag is inserted so the click event is never triggered. You should use something like [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to always be listening for the event.

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".delWebTile", function() {
    ...
});
```